# this stays for hours! what to do?

Tags: virtualbox, dkms

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up virtualbox-dkms (5.2.10-dfsg-6) ...
Removing old virtualbox-5.2.10 DKMS files...

-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  virtualbox
Version: 5.2.10
Kernel:  4.15.0-23-generic (x86_64)
-------------------------------------

Status: This module version was INACTIVE for this kernel.
depmod.......

DKMS: uninstall completed.

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 5.2.10
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new virtualbox-5.2.10 DKMS files...
Building for 4.15.0-23-generic
Building initial module for 4.15.0-23-generic
```

Comment: I have the same problem here, have you figured it out how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The system is waiting for a password in the background.

Type password 4 times (with <kbd>enter</kbd>).

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/8r3zov/stuck_at_building_initial_module/e0z7oli/